# How to make login from ios simulaor with facebook?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, authentication

When I'm trying to login, it shows me this error:

> error :Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0xa54db80
>   {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled,
>   com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts
>   Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error
>   7.)", com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=,
>   expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate:
>   0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}

And this works fine when I login from facebook (officially) login.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

Go to the settings app of your iPhone.
Open your Facebook Settings
Scroll down to your app and make sure your app allows facebook interaction.
This could happen on any device, therefore in your app you will have to make sure to handle this error correctly. I reckon you give the user feedback why Login With Facebook failed and ask the user to check their Facebook settings on their device.

```
 - (void)facebookSessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState)state error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            // handle successful login here
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

            if (error) {
                // handle error here, for example by showing an alert to the user
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Could not login with Facebook"
                                                                message:@"Facebook login failed. Please check your Facebook settings on your phone."
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

//AND OTHER WAY....... TRY ALSO........AND CHECK THIS...

check your Bundle identifier for your project and you give Bundle identifier for your app which create on developer.facebook.com that they are same or not.